# Disabling a controller page from being viewed

Tags: yii, access-control, yii-routing

I am an absolute newbie in the world of Yii and MVC.
My question is : Say if I have made a CRUD of some model and I have modified the "_form.php" partial to be used from some place else, for example a comment form which is used from the "post" view, and for example if my link for the creation of comment is :

```
http://localhost/example/comment/create
```

How do I stop this page from being accessed and only be called from the view of the "posts" page only?

Would I have to use **RBAC** for this? Is there any other method? Using "GET" methods maybe?

Comment: You should really read some basics before asking questions. There is [very good guide for yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/) or [this wiki with plenty resources](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/397/the-complete-beginner-s-study-guide-for-the-yii-framework/)

Comment: Like I said I am still learning and I tend to learn fast by delving into application making.

Comment: Thats why i posted some usefull links for you. In short, you can just remove actionCreate from your comment controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking if the referrer page is the one you want, using `getUrlReferrer()` or the magic property `urlReferrer`:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getUrlReferrer-detail

e.g.:

```
if(preg_match('/post\/view/', Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer) === 1) {
    // do something
}
```

Place this in your `comment/create` action.

Comment: So is this the only way? Do I need to set referres for all those pages that I do not want to be seen ?